# Do these points trace out a function? $ P(2^{2^s},2^{2^{-s}}) $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Do these points trace out a function? What is the functional equation?

$$ P(2^{2^s},2^{2^{-s}})$$ for $s\in\Bbb R.$

I know that $$ P(2^s,2^{-s}) $$ traces out the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$

Comment: well the trace for the points I'm asking about is pretty much the same form as $f(x)$ but the asympotes are now at $x,y=1$ as opposed to $x,y=0$

Comment: $y= \frac{1}{x-1}+1$ comes very close

Comment: It only traces one branch of the hyperbola $f(x) = 1/x$, the one in the first quadrant, because $2^s (= x)$ is always positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take $y=e^{\frac{(\ln2)^2}{\ln x}}$.

For all such points, we have $x_0=2^{2^s}$ and $y_0=2^{2^{-s}}$.

Taking the natural logarithm, we get $\ln x_0=\ln{2^{2^s}}=2^s\ln2$ and $\ln y_0=\ln{2^{2^{-s}}}=2^{-s}\ln2$.

The relation $\frac{\ln{x_0}}{\ln{2} }=\frac{\ln{2} }{\ln{y_0}}$ is then clear.