# What function does $P(2^{2^{2^s}},2^{2^{2^{-s}}})$ trace out?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function

This is related: [Do these points trace out a function? $ P(2^{2^s},2^{2^{-s}}) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438539/do-these-points-trace-out-a-function-p22s-22-s)

What function does $P(2^{2^{2^s}},2^{2^{2^{-s}}})$ trace out?

I tried going through the answer that was given in the previous post but could not figure it out for this extension of the problem. I don't understand how to find the function.

Comment: For fixed $s$, write $x = 2^{2^{2^s}}, y = 2^{2^{2^{-s}}}$. Then $\log_2(y) = f(\log_2(x))$, where $f$ is as in the previous question. So $y = 2^{f(\log_2(x))}$.

Comment: I don't see how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split this into a few steps:

- We can get from $x:=\color{red}{2^s}$ to $y:=\color{red}{2^{-s}}$ with $\color{red}{y=1/x}$.
- We can get from $x:=\color{orange}{2}^{\color{red}{2^s}}$ to $y:=\color{orange}{2}^{\color{red}{2^{-s}}}$ with
  $\color{red}{\log_2y=1/\log_2x}$, i.e. $\color{orange}{y=2^{1/\log_2x}}$.
- We can get from $x:=\color{limegreen}{2}^{\color{orange}{2}^{\color{red}{2^s}}}$ to $y:=\color{limegreen}{2}^{\color{orange}{2}^{\color{red}{2^{-s}}}}$ with
  $\color{orange}{\log_2y=2^{1/\log_2\log_2x}}$, i.e. $\color{limegreen}{y=2^{2^{1/\log_2\log_2x}}}$.

Comment: It looks like the right answer but it's not working when I actually plot it

Comment: @Ultradark Could you edit your question to show how you plotted it and what happened, and why you feel it's wrong somehow?

Comment: Oh I got it now